# variable becomes nil in numberOfRowsInTableView after being set in another method

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nstableview

My class looks like this :

```
@interface ApplicantPickerController : AppPage <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate> 
{
    School *school;
    __weak IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *familyList;
    __weak IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator *progressIndicator;
}
- (IBAction)alphabetButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

In the `alphabetButtonPressed` method, I'm fetching a json array from a webservice and assigning it to `familyList`. After doing this, I do `[tableView reload];`
When the control passes to the `- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView` method, `familyList` becomes `nil`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I'm using ARC for this project.
Cocoa/Objective-C newbie here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

---

Updated - Here is the implementation of the class :

```
@interface ApplicantPickerController ()

@end

@implementation ApplicantPickerController

- (IBAction)alphabetButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [progressIndicator startAnimation:self];

    NSString * addy = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@.php?function=applicant_lookup&schoolID=%@&alpha=%@&currentYear=%@&format=json", BASE_URL_SCHOOL, school->recordID, [sender title], school->CurrentYear];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:addy]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if(data) {
        //NSString * resp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSObject *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        if([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            familyList = nil;
            [tableView reloadData];
        }
        else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            familyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [familyList addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)json];
            //[_familyList retain];
            [tableView reloadData];
        }

        [progressIndicator stopAnimation:self];
    }
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [familyList count];
}

- (id)initWithMainView:(NSView *)_theView AndMainController:(NSViewController *)_theViewController AndNibName:(NSString *)nibName AndArgs:(NSArray *)_args
{
    self = [super initWithMainView:_theView AndMainController:_theViewController AndNibName:nibName AndArgs:_args];
    school = [args objectAtIndex:0];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Show the code that initializes that array and `numberOfRowsInTableView:`.

Comment: make sure you are allocating familyList before assigning the parsed values .

Comment: @trojanfoe Just updated with the implementation.

Comment: @RIYAZ I am doing that. Just updated with the implementation.

Comment: Why aren't you using properties (`@property`)?

Comment: @Popeye I tried making familyList a property. It is doing the same thing.

Comment: I would suggest adding an NSLog option to both of the if-else inside of the NSURLConnection completion handler, just to make sure which one gets executed. Could be that the first one being called (meaning json is a dictionary), because there you are the one setting it to nil.

Comment: @AMI289 that is not the problem. I've made sure (using breakpoints) that the response from the web service is an array.

Comment: Are you using any other table view delegate/data source methods in your code? maybe one of them is getting called upon `[tableView reloadData]` and they 'break' the array.

Comment: @AMI289 No. The only one I'm using is - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I discovered a bug by apple, but following is how I solved this issue.

I was setting the `NSTableView` delegate and datasource in the UI builder (by right clicking and making the connections with the mouse). For some reason, if I set the `delegate` and `dataSource` in the code (specifically in the `awakeFromNib` method), the issue gets resolved.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```